# Is my batch contaminated("infected")?

Tags: stout, contamination

Its been fermenting for about 10 days, and I'm just now noticing these white spots.
Is this what the start of an infection looks like? If so, is there anything I should do?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could be the yeast, so nothing to worry about. Does it smell weird?

Comment: it looks like my stout, that i just made, as above what does it smell like? does it smell like beer, or something foul? please describe, also what yeast did you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like flocculant yeast, if you look close it should be the same color as the trub on the bottom if it is. May see them pulling off and coming to the top, but it's hard to see in a dark beer.

Looks like it's still putting off CO2. All that should fall back in as fermentation finishes off.

Comment: I have seen floculant yeast rising attached to bubbles then fall back down after.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the yeast is still eating all that goodness as long as it smells okay don't worry wait a few days remove the air lock smell it then take a reading..

Answer (score 2):

I had white spots om my dark stout beer, as I am new to brewing I looked up on a lot of forums, it's just yeast spots not contamination. I sterilised a tea strainer and tried to catch the spots but they disappeared as I touched them. Like the other answers if it smells OK and not smell of off water then it should be OK.  Hope this helps